# How to set orientation in two different mode , in two layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, screen-orientation

I have layout that is called `Main.XML` and I set the orientation to portrait in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. I designed this layout for Honeycomb too and placed it in the `layout-xlarge-mdpi` folder, but I want to use the  `Main.XML` in `layout-xlarge-mdpi` only in landscape orientation.

Now, how can do this?

Thanks

Comment: you want one layout in portrait and another in landscape mode right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place your `main.xml` in `layout-xlarge-land`, then it will be used only in landscape orientation
Refer [Supporting Multiple Screens (Using configuration qualifiers)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

> Android supports several configuration
>   qualifiers that allow you to control
>   how the system selects your
>   alternative resources based on the
>   characteristics of the current device
>   screen. A configuration qualifier is a
>   string that you can append to a
>   resource directory in your Android
>   project and specifies the
>   configuration for which the resources
>   inside are designed.

Edit:
If you provide an `main.xml` in `layout` folder and another `main.xml` in `layout-xlarge-land`, then

- for an `extra large landscape orientation` it will take the `main.xml from layout-xlarge-land`
- for `all other, that is in landscape or portrait orientation` it will take the `main.xml from layout`

Refer [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more details

Comment: Yup that's right , but it means the portrait mode will be disable in xlarge mode?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `layout-xlarge-mdpi-land` folder and place your `main.xml` in that

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be done like this:

1. Detect screen size programmtically in you onCreate. http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg144381.html
2. Set orientation according to screen size, like this:

   if(screen size is large)
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
   else
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Not sure if it's the best way though.

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest insert the following code in whichever activity you want to run in landscape mode(In this case Main Activity)

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```