# Android: Landscape Child Activity in a Portrait Tab Activity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a tab activity that has three child activities, A, B and C. Child activities A and B are to follow the orientation of the tab activity.  i.e. if the tab activity is in portrait so should A and B, if the tag activity is landscape so should A and B.

Child activity C should always be in landscape orientation regardless of the tab activity orientation (preferably following android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape").  Is this possible?

I have tried using android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" for C in the manifest which doesn't work.  The best I can manage is to use the following in C (in onResume())

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

and for A and B I use (also in onResume())

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

But this flips the entire tab which is not the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie and all I can say is that the tab layout is very picky about what you do in it. try making it all landscape, then changing the orientarion of the two a/b tabs after C is working... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `AndroidManifest` :

```
<activity android:name=".YourClass" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Comment: I've tried all variations of android:screenOrientation with the TabActivity and the child activities.  I just cannot get a child activity to be in landscape orientation while the parent tab activity remains in portrait orientation.

Comment: Check it out , it might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557107/how-to-set-orientation-in-two-different-mode-in-two-layout/6557143#6557143

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Dont know if it is a good solution, but the workaround I found is as follows:
Put `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` before the `setContentView()` of `onCreate()` method of Activity C. And put `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);` before the `setContentView()` of `onCreate()` method of other two Activities (A and B).

Any other elegant solution is highly appreciated.