# How to set different orientation changing settings on phone and tablet?

Tags: android-sensors, android, android-orientation

I making an app both for phones and galaxy tab.
I want to be only portrait mode on phones, and portrait and landscape as well in tabs.

So far i got this code snippet:

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            int width = dm.widthPixels;
            int height = dm.heightPixels;

            if(!(width>=800 && height>=1280))
            {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            }



            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

            //... more code below
```

So i just check the screen size and if it is the tablet's 800x1280, i do nothing and orientation change is active. If it is not 800x1280 i do:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

I thought it will be work fine, but for some random bug, it is not working every time..
Lets say for about ten times, the orientation just changes to landscape to a second on phones then it changes back to portrait. So a little buggy a little wrong.

Is it another better way to do this?

Comment: And what do you want to do for hybrids like the galaxy note? They would be seen as a "phone" by your code. I suggest you don't decide for the user what's better, but make it a choice? maybe some users want to be able to change portrait/landscape, you could make a 'lock' button in your settings, but frankly, even that is allready in the OS?

Comment: please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557107/how-to-set-orientation-in-two-different-mode-in-two-layout

Comment: As i know, galaxy note has exactly same width and height as galaxy tab, so my code would handle it like a tab. Good for me for such a big chunk of table like the galaxy note's screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can set to screenOrientation in mainfest

```
<activity
            android:name=".Dis"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```